# How to get the same log output that you see in Xcode console but in terminal instead?

Tags: xcode, firebase, terminal, firebase-dynamic-links, xcrun

I'd like to view the logs from the console inside a terminal window instead. This is so that I can test Firebase Dynamic Links (because I need to run:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted 'My Dynamic Link Here'
```

so I need to open an Xcode simulator and then run this command. The problem is I'm not able to see the logging in the console embedded in Xcode, so I'd like to view the logs that the app would write in a terminal window instead. How can I accomplish this?

I tried using:

```
xcrun simctl spawn 66D3600B-8911-4308-A98D-ADF3881091F2 log stream --level info
```

or

```
xcrun simctl spawn 66D3600B-8911-4308-A98D-ADF3881091F2 log stream --level debug
```

but neither gave me the logs--to be honest I don't even know what I'm looking at with those outputs.

Comment: Sounds like an xy question. Would you like to see logging after launching the app using `xcrun simctl openurl`? There is a way to do that. Would you like to know what it is?

Comment: @matt Yes, that's exactly what I need. Just so I can troubleshoot my Firebase Dynamic Links

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/tricks-for-testing-external-links/